# Unable to retrieve image attributes from saved KineticJS canvas state

Tags: kineticjs

I am trying to save canvas state involving images on the server and then retrieve the state at a later stage. I am using KineticJS library.
I am saving the state by using stage.toJSON() and then recreating it using stage2.load() but the resulting JSON created from stage.toJSON doesnt conatain any data relating to the images and subsequently stage2 has all the shapes except images which are undefined.

Something else should be done to make the json include the image data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON generated by toJSON() has placeholders for your image objects.. the images themselves arent part of that json string.. from what I understand, you'll need to manage saving and restoring of images separately. See this example

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-load-complex-stage-with-kineticjs/

In essence, load everything, get hold of placeholders for images from rendered data and set your image.

Comment: ok, one more thing.. while creating images initially (before toJSON), make sure you set the 'id' property for the Kinetic.Image.. this will result in toJSON'ified string to have the 'id' set which can then be used while loading.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue..

JSON doesn't load images and you'll have to call them again..cause of security issues and all..

But you can add one src attribute inside your image loader function...

and reload the stage using stage.load(json)

Try this js fiddle..
this will definitely help:
http://jsfiddle.net/sKymY/

Regards